# use python 3.4 instead of python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.4, python-3.5

I have a script that I found on the internet that worked in Python 3.4, but not Python 3.5. I'm not too familiar in python, but it has the

> `#!/usr/bin/env python3`

schlebang at the top of the file. And it also throws this exception when I try to run it:

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "/home/username/folder/script.py", line 18, in
>
> doc = opener.open(url)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 472, in open
>
> response = meth(req, response)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 582, in http_response
>       'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 504, in error
>
> result = self._call_chain(*args)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 444, in _call_chain
>
> result = func(*args)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 968, in http_error_401
>       url, req, headers)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 921, in http_error_auth_reqed
>
> return self.retry_http_basic_auth(host, req, realm)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 931, in retry_http_basic_auth
>
> return self.parent.open(req, timeout=req.timeout)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 472, in open
>
> response = meth(req, response)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 582, in http_response
>       'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 510, in error
>       return self._call_chain(*args)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 444, in _call_chain
>       result = func(*args)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 590, in http_error_default
>
> raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)

Python isn't really my preferred langage, so I don't know what to do. This is a script that's supposed to access my Gmail account and pull new mails from it. Do you guys have any suggestions? I'm using Arch Linux, if that helps.

Comment: What is the actual exception?

Comment: I think it's urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized

Comment: with that error it is very unlikely that running it under 3.4 will change anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Variant A:**
Run this script as `python3.4 /path/to/script`

**Variant B:**
Change the schebang to `#!/usr/bin/python3.4`